# how can i correct error : Failed to start java spring app : "Consider defining a bean of type '...' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring

I try to setup a java spring angular app and i just add my service and i have this message :

2024-03-19T17:12:29.755+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 16680 (C:\Users\lbourgade-aubanel\Documents\demo\demo\target\classes started by lbourgade-aubanel in C:\Users\lbourgade-aubanel\Documents\demo\demo)
2024-03-19T17:12:29.760+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-19T17:12:30.871+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-03-19T17:12:30.880+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-19T17:12:30.881+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-03-19T17:12:31.003+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-19T17:12:31.005+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1196 ms
2024-03-19T17:12:31.074+01:00  WARN 16680 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'garageController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'garageService': Error creating bean with name 'garageService' defined in file [C:\Users\lbourgade-aubanel\Documents\demo\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\service\GarageService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.GarageRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-03-19T17:12:31.079+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-19T17:12:31.101+01:00  INFO 16680 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-19T17:12:31.134+01:00 ERROR 16680 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.GarageService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.GarageRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.GarageRepository' in your configuration.

PS C:\Users\lbourgade-aubanel\Documents\demo\demo> Consider defining a bean of type

I try to remove @Autowired in my Controller cause i want to inject service. When i do this it work well but i cant do a get post or put it crash. and when i let @Autowired
private GarageService garageService; it does not launch app

Here is my controller :

```
package com.example.demo.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo.model.Car;
import com.example.demo.service.GarageService;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class GarageController {
    @Autowired
    private GarageService garageService;

    @RequestMapping("/cars")
    public List<Car> getCar(){
        return garageService.getCars();
    }
    @RequestMapping("/car/{id}")
    public Car getCar(@PathVariable long id) {
        return garageService.getCar(id);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/car/{id}")
    public void deleteCar(@PathVariable long id){
        garageService.deleteCar(id);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/cars")
    public void addCar(@RequestBody Car car){
        garageService.addCar(car);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/car/{id}")
    public void updtaeCar(@RequestBody Car car, @PathVariable long id){
        garageService.updateCar(car, id);
    }

}
```

and here is my repo :

```
package com.example.demo.repository;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Car;
@Repository
public interface GarageRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {

}
```